# How to use "Study with me Live Videos"

Tags: independent-study

i see the popularity of study with me videos in on a rise at a rapid pace.
Could someone please tell me how to use those videos?
thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "how to use these videos"? Aren't you supposed to watch them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put one on in the background and study at the same time. The videos are meant to mimic sitting next to a friend in the library working quietly together.